# Group values by filename extension pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many types of files (.svg, .png, csv, etc). And there are some files which do not have an extension.

How can I group those files without an extension and make a pie chart like this one?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'file_name': ['filelist.xml', 'sheet002', 'sheet005.htm', 'image1.jpg', 'image3.jpg',
   'kings.xls', 'Kings.png', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals.pdf', 'Royals.csv', 'Riders.xml'],
   'created_at': ['2020-01-01 23:00:34'] *2 + ['2018-01-01 13:01:34'] *3 + ['2020-01-01 22:00:00'] *4 + ['2018-02-01 23:00:34']*3,
   'size':[8760] * 3 + [789] *4 + [863] *2 + [673] *3})


df_unknown=df[df['file_name'].apply(lambda x: len(x.rsplit('.', 1))) < 2]
```

EDIT
I have so many values. The pie chart cannot show them all.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to set those values not containing a `.` to unknown, and plot a pie chart from the [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
(df.file_name.where(df.file_name.str.contains(r'\.'), 'unknown')
             .str.split('.').str[-1]
             .value_counts()
             .plot.pie())
```

Or another way could be to use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
(df.file_name.str.extract(r'(\.\w+$)', expand=False)
                 .fillna('unknown')
                 .value_counts()
                 .plot.pie())
```

[image]

**Update**

To get a chart of size `sum` in each group:

```
(df['size'].groupby(df.file_name.str.extract(r'(\.\w+$)', expand=False)
                    .fillna('unknown'))
            .sum().plot.pie())
```

[image]

Comment: How can I do it with the size of the files instead of the count?

Comment: I was using this: ```df.groupby('extension')['size'].sum().plot.pie(y='size', figsize=(7,7))```

Comment: It extracts the extension. Check by yourself :)  Run: `df.file_name.str.extract(r'(\.\w+$)', expand=False)` @Aizzaac

Answer (score 1):

Try [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) with [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
import os
(df['size'].groupby(df['file_name'].map(os.path.splitext)
                                   .str[-1]
                                   .replace({'': 'unknown'}))
           .sum())

file_name
.csv         673
.htm        8760
.jpg        1578
.pdf         673
.png         789
.xls         789
.xml        9433
unknown    10486
Name: size, dtype: int64
```

From here, plotting should be straightforward:

```
_.plot.pie()
plt.show()
```

Comment: And if I want to use the size?

Comment: I was using this: ```df.groupby('extension')['size'].sum().plot.pie(y='size', figsize=(7,7))```

Comment: @Aizzaac Ah I see you wanted to work with the size column.

Comment: yes. the 'size' column. But I have so many values that the pie chart does not display them all properly. do you know how to solve that?

Comment: @Aizzaac take the top 5-10 most common values and mark everything else as "other"